# Can I mix module-level methods into modules but not classes?

Tags: ruby

I want to do something like

```
module MyStuff
  def my_method
  end
end

class Module
  include MyStuff
end
```

but in a way so that I can do

```
module SomeModule
  my_method
end
```

but not

```
class SomeClass
  my_method
end
```

Since `Class` inherits from `Module` I suspect it's tricky, without explicitly undefining the module's methods. But maybe that's the only way?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do that is to rely on inherited:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited

When you inherit you could dynamically define or undefine the method based on whatever criteria you might have.

Another approach you could take is to inherit the method for both, and inside the method look at what entity you're in and simply do nothing for class.

Just 2 options. There are probably couple more that escape me.

**Update:**

For modules you use included: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included

The spirit is the same though.

here is a full example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
module BaseModule
    def self.included(subclass)
        if subclass.name.eql?("A")
            subclass.send(:define_method, "method1") do
                puts "Method1 in #{subclass.name}"
            end
        end
    end
end

class A 
    include BaseModule 
end

class B
    include BaseModule
end


A.new.method1
B.new.method1
```

B.new.method1 will complain that it does not have a method1

**Update2**

Reread the questions, and here is what I hope is the final solution (it builds on previous):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
module BaseModule
    def self.included(sub)
        return if sub.kind_of? Class
        sub.send(:define_method, "method1") do
            puts "Method1 in #{sub.name}"
        end
    end
end

module SomeModule
    include BaseModule
end

class A 
    include SomeModule 
end

class B
    include BaseModule
end


A.new.method1
B.new.method1
```

A will have method 1 because it include from SomeModule where this is define.
B will not have it as it attempts to do this directly from BaseModule.

**Update3**

> Using included for this is clever. A problem here is that I want
>   my_method to be available in every module automatically, but not in
>   any class, per the example in the question. The real, non-simplified
>   problem I want to solve is that I want to mix a moduleful of
>   module-level/class-level methods into all modules, and all
>   Object-derived classes, but not BasicObject (which Object inherits
>   from)

You can do this the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module UberModule
    def make_it_so
        puts "make_it_so in #{self.class}"
    end
end

class Module
    include UberModule    
end

class Class
    undef_method :make_it_so
end

module TestModule
end

class Test
end

TestModule::make_it_so
Test.new.make_it_so
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `included` for this is clever. A problem here is that I want `my_method` to be available in every module automatically, but not in any class, per the example in the question. The real, non-simplified problem I want to solve is that I want to mix a moduleful of module-level/class-level methods into all modules, and all `Object`-derived classes, but not `BasicObject` (which `Object` inherits from).

Comment: just to make sure I understand the problem is that if you open up Object and include the module you will end up with the methods both on modules and classes?

Comment: Not quite: if I open up `class Module` and include my own module, then those methods will become module-level/class-level methods on every module and every class (seeing as `Class` inherits from `Module`). The problem is that I don't want them on the `BasicObject` class and all its subclasses.

Comment: yeah... think we are talking about the same thing. let me throw together a quick example:x

Comment: Thanks for that! Yeah, that was my plan B ("I suspect it's tricky, without explicitly undefining the module's methods. But maybe that's the only way?"). That's probably the way I'll have to go. Thanks so much for all your help on this!